# Android send email with multiple attachment using file provider

Tags: android, sendmail, android-fileprovider

Android App Problems sending an email with multiple attachments using File Provider.

I was using `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse( "file://"+csvFilePath));` and I have no issues sending single attachment file. Then I need to send multiple attachments. I have a problem to get it working.

In my AndroidManifest.xml I specify the provider with the following code :

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

Here is my xml/provider_paths

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths>
    <external-path
        name="myfiles"
        path="Android/data/com.example.abc/files/Documents"/>
    </paths>
```

Send email code and files path are :

```
csvFilePath : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.abc/files/Documents/Test123.csv
       xyzFilePath : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.abc/files/Documents/xyz123.txt
     //attach multiple file
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

        intent.setType("text/plain");
        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

        //uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(csvFilePath)));
        //uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(xyzFilePath)));

        // using file provider

        File csvFile = new File(csvFilePath);
        File xyzFile = new File(xyzFilePath);
        uris.add(FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", csvFile ));
        uris.add(FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", xyzFile ));

        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + abc@xyz.com));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);


        startActivity(intent);
```

Exception raises during sending `mailandroid.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE dat=mailto:xxx.xxxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx flg=0x10000001 clip={null U:content://com.example.abc.provider/myfiles/Test123.csv ...} (has extras) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution with the following code :

```
 xml/provider_paths
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>

File baseDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory  (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "ABC");


 if (!baseDir.exists()) {
    baseDir.mkdirs();
 }

 Log.i("Debug", "baseDir " + baseDir.toString());
            File f1 = new File(baseDir, "File1.txt");
            writeToFile(f1, "This is file 1 contents 888888888");
            Log.i("Debug", "f1 path" + f1.getAbsolutePath());
            File f2 = new File(baseDir, "File2.txt");
            writeToFile(f2, "This is file 2 contents 123456");
            Log.i("Debug", "f2 path" + f2.getAbsolutePath());


            String f1path = f1.toString();
            String f2path = f2.toString();
            string EXTRA_RECIPIENT = "janedoe@abc.com";
            String message = "Test message 12345678 this is a test. ";
            sendMail(f1path, f2path, message, EXTRA_RECIPIENT);


 private void sendMail(String f1path, String f2path, String message, String mailTo) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test multiple attachments");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{mailTo});

    File f1new = new File(f1path);
    File f2new = new File(f2path);

    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

    uris.add(FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", f1new ));
    uris.add(FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", f2new ));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The gmail or mail sending apps may be disabled in your mobile. Kindly check the apps are enabled. 
This ActivityNotFoundException occurs mainly when there is no application to handle the intent.

Comment: I check gmail and other were enabled. I was able to send mail when I not using the file provider. Under clip={null U:content://com.example.abc.provider/myfiles/Test123.csv ...} (has extras) . I think it indicate there issues to find the file.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I need to send multiple attachments. I have a problem to get it
>   working.

Example for multiple attachments:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test multiple");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "multiple attachments");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{recipient_address});
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File("/path/to/first/file")));
uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File("/path/to/second/file")));
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
```

Finish with a call to startActivity() passing intent.

Comment: Uri.fromFile no longer work on the latest Android that is why I switch to  use file provider. My file provider code I just posted work now.